# Analyze the run time of the function below and assume worst case scenario (in terms of n)

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

[image]

i think that the loops runs o(N) times and wanted to confirmed that and even to expanding knowledge over the steps.
Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Why do *you* think it is `O(N)`?

Comment: Try plotting `n` against `count` on a graph for `n = 2^k`, and see if it looks linear to you.

Comment: Note: [For many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4581301), don't use images of text. The only times you should use an image as a source of essential information is when the question is about the image, a graphics programming problem, or when the image is literally worth a thousand words, you need to unambiguously explain the configuration of a program with a GUI dialog.

Comment: How many combinations of `i` and `j` do you visit?  Try drawing them in a square.  If you wind up with an *area*, that's `O(n^2)`.  A *line* would be `O(n)`.  Can you come up with a formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let k be the least positive number such that 2^k > n.

Observe that your first iteration runs no more than 2^k times.
since, n < 2^k, n/2 < 2^{k-1}, hence your second loop runs no more than 2^{k-1} times,
third loop runs 2^{k-2} time, so on and so forth.

Total number of iterations can be upper bounded by 2^k + 2^{k-1} .... 2^0 = 2^{k+1}-1.

We assumed that  k is the least postive number such that 2^k > n, which implies 2^{k-1} <= n
multiplying by 4 on both sides and substracting gives us, 2^{k+1}-1 <= 4n-1

hence total number of iterations is O(n). Although the upper bound 4n-1 is sloppy, it is enough to prove asymtotics. (in reality your loop runs approximately 2n times)